# Ionic v4 App debug window automatically redirects from http to https

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working on my first ionic v4 application, when I try to debug the app on the browser locally with 'ionic serve'with the following command:

ionic serve

> ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100

```
[ng] i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8100/webpack-dev-server/
[ng] i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
[ng] i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to //index.html
[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!
```

It launches a new window of my default browser 'chrome' but I can't access the app, all I get is ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR, it seems is redirecting all requests from http to https, but if I open a new incognito instance and I manually set the address to http://localhost:8100/ I can test my application, it's also happening on IE.

I have searched the web and I can't find any reference to anyone having the same problem, I'm not sure if it's caused by ionic, the browsers or my windows machines. I tested it on another windows machine with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with f12 / developer tools open, that disables the cache so any redirects that might have got caught up in it would be cleared. You might still need to do a ctrl-f5 / hard refresh.

Also, not a fix, but if you have that message I think you can just expand the message at the bottom and choose continue anyway.

Comment: I tried with developers tools open, control+F5 neither worked for me. Also it doesn't let me continue

Comment: hmm sorry thats all my ideas

Answer (score 0):

Please, verify if you have this meta tag on your header

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

this will change every http request to https